# How to prevent automatic scaling under 96 dpi

Tags: nattable

In NatTable version 2 an autoscale was added while the tables are being created, supported by default DPI converters: `DefaultHorizontalDpiConverter, DefaultVerticalDpiConverter`. In version 1 everything under 96 DPI was not scaled down, however, now in version 2 for lower DPIs NatTables are scaled down hence images look ugly, fonts are ok:

72dpi - not ok:

[image]
[image]
[image]

96dpi - ok:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What would be the simplest way to prevent default scaling under 96 DPI?

Answer (score 0):

The feature that was added with NatTable 2.0 is a complete dynamic scaling and the full support for all DPI. The following blog post should give some more details [NatTable – dynamic scaling enhancements](http://blog.vogella.com/2020/03/05/nattable-dynamic-scaling-enhancements/)

Actually I wonder what is "ugly" with lower DPIs. At least on modern displays it should not be an issue. The only thing I could think of are the images. But typically downscaling doesn't make images ugly. So it would be really interesting to know what the issue is.

You have two options to handle that:

1. As you can scale NatTable dynamically at runtime, you can simply execute the `ConfigureScalingCommand` to force the scaling you want. Note that this needs to be done AFTER `NatTable#configure()`.

   ```
   if (Display.getDefault().getDPI().x < 96) {
       natTable.doCommand(
           new ConfigureScalingCommand(new FixedScalingDpiConverter(96)));
   }
   ```
2. If you even want to block lower scalings on the dynamic scaling, you can implement a custom `ConfigureScalingCommandHandler` that checks for the dpiFactor in the `IDpiConverter` and if that is lower than 1 register a `FixedScalingDpiConverter` on the `SizeConfigs`. That custom `ConfigureScalingCommandHandler`then needs to be registered on the `DataLayer` to replace the default.

The second approach is probably a bit more complicated and needs a better understanding of NatTable internals. And it blocks the dynamic scaling feature to really zoom out on huge tables. So it depends on your use cases which approach to use. Typically the first option should be sufficient.

BTW, if the images are the issue, changing the scaling at runtime without re-registering the images could also cause a rendering issue. The reason for this is that images are stored in the `ImageRegistry` and they need to be updated there in case of scaling changes. For approach 1. that means to register all images in the `ConfigRegistry` again after the `ConfigureScalingCommand`. At least if you are not using themes or CSS styling.

Comment: Hi @DirkFauth, thank you for your hints, I'll try them. Yes, the problem is with scaled down images on Mac. I edited my question to provide some examples.

Comment: OK, the problem really is that the automatic downscaling of images produces such ugly variants. NatTable does not provide the images for 72 dpi, the lowest dpi provided is 96 dpi. You could of course also fix this by using images that are available for 72 dpi.
The thing that worries me more is that the font is actually NOT downscaled, although NatTable has an explicit handling for font scaling. While the rendering is using 72 dpi for grid and images, the font seems to be still 96 dpi. That doesn't happen on Windows.

Comment: Thank you. So the simplest solution would be to go table by table and reregister every single image used in them? By reregistering the image you mean to register every single `CELL_PAINTER` config attribute in the `configRegistry` with all CellPainterDecorator-s or can I somehow reregister just image.

Comment: That depends on your painters, e.g. you can configure an `ImagePainter` that has a static image or a dynamic one. For all painters with static images, like for example `CheckboxPainter` you need to re-register the painters. I therefore suggest to use `ThemeConfigurations` as this makes it very simply to update.